# Imbalance Data - More than One Class

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, dataset

I have imbalanced data and I want to train model on it. But it has more than 1 class imbalance according to different columns. The problem is that all the solutions I have come across is dealing with just 1 class imbalance. How can I approach this problem ?

Comment: Class imbalance turns out not to be a problem! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he